# Can you access prototype properties within prototype functions?

Tags: javascript, prototype

If I declare a class like this:

```
var Foo = function() {};
```

And add properties to it like this:

```
Foo.prototype.bar = "";
```

Why can't I access the property like this:

```
Foo.prototype.setBar = function( value ) {
   this.bar = value;
}
```

In my code I don't have `Foo.prototype.bar` in scope of `Foo.prototype.SetBar`. this.bar is showing undefined.

**UPDATE**

Ok maybe I should be a little more specific since for some reason my code is not running.

```
var JSocketServer = function( options, callback ) {
    if( typeof(options) != "object" ) {
        callback("Invalid object passed for options");
        return;
    }
    if( typeof(options.port) != "number" ) {
        callback("Must specify a port number in options");
        return;
    }

    // Hook up Event Emitter Functionality
    mevents.EventEmitter.call(this);

    this.initServer( options, callback );
};

// Set up static class properties
JSocketServer.prototype.socketPool = {};
JSocketServer.prototype.socketMap = {};

// Inherit from EventEmitter
mutil.inherits(JSocketServer, mevents.EventEmitter);


JSocketServer.prototype.initServer = function( options, callback ) {
    // Hook up raw tcp server
    var jserver = this;
    var server = mnet.createServer( function( socket ) {
        jserver.handleSocket( socket, callback );
    });

    server.listen(options.port, function() {
        console.log("Socket Server is bound");
    })

    this.serverListener( server )
}

JSocketServer.prototype.handleSocket = function( socket, callback ) {
    var jsocketServer = this;
    var jsocket = new mjsocket(socket);

    console.log("Socket: "+jsocket.socketID+" connected");

    this.socketPool[jsocket.socketID] = jsocket;

    jsocket.on("data", function( data ) {
        // Add socket id to socket map
        jsocketServer.socketMap[jsocket.moduleID] = jsocket.socketID;
    });

    jsocket.on("close", function(err) {
        jsocketServer.removeSocket(jsocket.socketID);
    });

    // Callback with JSocket
    callback( undefined, jsocket );
}
```

Now inside `JSocketServer.prototype.handleSocket` where I'm trying to assign a key and value to `this.socketPool`, it's saying that `this.socketPool` is undefined. Now from my understanding and what you guys are saying, this shouldn't be.

**UPDATE**

Here's a JS Fiddle of my code http://jsfiddle.net/bZrtn/. I have 2 classes JSocketServer and JSocket and they're being used by the APP at the bottom.

Comment: How is `setBar` called? Of course you can access (and set) it!

Comment: Note that both `bar` and `setBar` are shared properties between instances (since you set them on the `prototype`)...`this.bar` is different than `Foo.prototype.bar`

Comment: @Ian: Althought this.bar will fall through to the prototype if it hasn't been defined on the instance.

Comment: @Ian I'm not exactly sure what you mean. If you run the code the OP has, then do this: `var foo = new Foo(); f.setBar("asdf");`,...`foo.bar` equals `"asdf"`, and `Foo.prototype.bar` is still `""`

Comment: @Ian+Ian This is confusing :|

Comment: @Ian Ahh, I think I see what you mean. Say you just did `var foo = new Foo();`...`foo.bar` will be `""` (because it looks up the prototype chain). I think I just misunderstood your comment when I first read it

Comment: @meagar Who knows, maybe there's only one Ian talking to himself...

Comment: @Ian - (IanW says): This is quite confusing commenting! Yeah going up the prototype chain is what I was highlighting. I've fleshed out my answer and added a link to try and illustrate this.

Comment: I've added a JSFiddle to my answer that illustrates demonstrates your question in action, and shows that you can do this without issue.

Comment: Voted to close as it's unclear what you're asking. You **can** access the property, exactly like you've written. What do you mean by "access", if not get the value defined by the prototype?

Comment: @meagar Well technically you can't set the prototype value using the code he's given - you'll be setting an instance property. I imagine the confusion is around instance/prototype properties and when each apply.

Comment: Josh - could you setup a JSFiddle to demo the error?

Comment: Sure, I've never set one up so I suppose it's time I learn. I'll have to use something else since I'm running this on node.

Comment: @JoshElias Just setup a minimal example, break as many dependencies as you can to illustrate the problem. JSFiddle should work fine if you can extract a small snippet.

Comment: @Ian: You can also call `Foo.prototype.setBar(…)` to set the prototype property. Of course, *when* it is called on an instance it will create a property there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> // Set up static class properties
> JSocketServer.prototype.socketPool = {};
> JSocketServer.prototype.socketMap = {};
>
> // Inherit from EventEmitter
> mutil.inherits(JSocketServer, mevents.EventEmitter);
> ```

and

> ```
> // Set static class properties
> JSocket.prototype.moduleID = "";
> JSocket.prototype.dataArray = [];
> JSocket.prototype.dataString = "";
>
> // Inherit from EventEmitter
> mutil.inherits(JSocket, mevents.EventEmitter);
> ```

are the parts that make your code not work. [`utils.inherit`](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor) will **overwrite** the `.prototype` of `JSocketServer` (and `JSocket`) with a new, *empty* object that inherits from `EventEmitter`.

Do the assignments to the prototype object only after you have inherited!

```
// Inherit from EventEmitter first
mutil.inherits(JSocketServer, mevents.EventEmitter);

// then set up static class properties
JSocketServer.prototype.socketPool = {};
JSocketServer.prototype.socketMap = {};

…

// Inherit from EventEmitter first
mutil.inherits(JSocket, mevents.EventEmitter);

// then set static class properties
JSocket.prototype.moduleID = "";
JSocket.prototype.dataArray = [];
JSocket.prototype.dataString = "";
```

---

Btw, for static *class* properties you might as well (better?) put them on the constructor directly instead of the prototype, i.e.

```
JSocketServer.socketPool = {};
JSocketServer.socketMap = {};
```

and then always reference them explicitly with this full-qualifed name, instead of as (inherited) instance properties.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much. Can you elaborate on how declaring them is better that way? Does this work if I have multiple instances of JSocketServer? Can functions be declared like that as well?

Comment: As you say, they are *static* properties of the *class* itself. They have nothing to do with instances. Yes, you can assign ("declare" is the wrong term) any values as properties of the constructor function, including functions.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can but only when retrieving the value. Setting the value will create an instance propety. If you specify an instance property it will be returned instead of the prototype value. This means you could have:

```
Foo.prototype.radius = 5;
Foo.prototype.diameter = function() {
   return this.radius * 2;
};

var circle = new Foo();
console.log(circle.diameter()); // prints 10
circle.radius = 10;
console.log(circle.diameter()); // prints 20 just for this instance
```

Here's  a diagram that illustrates and an example based on a circle from the following site http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch08_04.htm

[image]

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95W4z/) to demonstrate original question.

Comment: Why the downvote? Is my answer incorrect in someway? If so please enlighten me :)

Comment: I don't know who would downvote that. One of the best answers I've ever gotten. I've updated my question to be more specific since I still can't figure out why it won't run.

Comment: I know I could do "this.socketPool = {}" inside the constructor but I thought that properties worked the same as functions in that if I declare them with prototype they get initialized at compile time instead of initialized at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The answer was indeed in the full code. I upvoted all your comments and answer for your efforts